# Error with the promise/catch from a Firestore query

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I've modified the code below a bit but this is an externally facing endpoint where a mobile client can ping this endpoint and send some pushes to appropriate users.

However, in my console, I'm getting an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: assert.isNotOk is not a function

```
function myFunc(request, response) {
  var db = firestore.firestore();
  db.collection("myCollection")
    .doc(request.params.someParam)
    .get()
    .then(docSnapshot => {

      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        for (var userId of request.params.userIds) {
           sendPush(userId, request.params);
           continue;

      } else {
        response.error("Unable to get param");
      }

    }).catch((error) => {
      assert.isNotOk(error, 'Promise error');
      done();
    });;
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation for node's `assert`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html), there is no method called `isNotOk`.  However, this is a method called [`ok`](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_ok_value_message).  In any event, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do with that line, since you already know at that point that there's an error.  Perhaps you just want to log it?

Comment: I was getting a previous error that I was missing a `catch` block so I was just adding it in to run without error